# Android Glide Image Loading Library show blurred images

Tags: android, gridview, android-glide, image-loading

I know this question was asked already, but their answers didn't solve my problem.

I am using Glide in `GridView`

when `GridView` displays the pictures, it looks like this

[image]

I kept waiting but nothing changed. Then after scrolling the `GridView`, all the images suddenly appeared as shown below.

[image]

So, how to get better quality images without having to scroll? Is there any alternative solution for this problem?

I wrote my `Glide` code like this

```
 Glide.with(activity)
                .load(R.drawable.xyz)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.img_hold)
                .into(imgView);
```

Answer (score 1):

found the problem. the image get blur or pixelated is because you doesn't set a fix width value in my imageview like this :

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="100dp"
```

after i give it a fixed value like this:

```
android:layout_width="170dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
```

all image is loaded nicely.

but I had tested on picasso lib, they load all image nicely although with `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Comment: Picasso lib is not comfortable for small memory devices

Comment: then try above solution by set fix height and width for imageview before loading.

Comment: It's work perfectly, but can't implement because it's not looking well

Comment: you have to determine width and height at runtime by device height and width calculation and then set it by layoutparams before loading with Glide.